# Unable to return NULL in a function that expects an integer return type

Tags: c

**Warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default] 
return NULL;**

I am trying to return NULL in my fucntion, but it's not working out and I don't understand why it is so. Below is my code, but I will not post the entire thing since I am only having problems with the return statement. I hope you can understand.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

typedef struct {
 int* data;
 unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;

int intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
{
    if(ia == NULL)
    {
        return NULL; // problem here, I want to return NULL if intarr_t*ia is null
    }
    else
    {
     // remaining code here, but is uncessary
     return 0;
     }
 }
```

My final question is also how do I check if the char array filename is NULL?

Would I do this:

```
if (filename == NULL)
{
     return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Well, the return type is declared as an integer. If it returned a pointer to an integer, then you could return NULL.

Comment: I am slightly confused, would that mean I have to change my function declaration?

Comment: also worth knowing that null is actually the address 0... http://c-faq.com/null/macro.html

Comment: Isn't returning 0 a sign that everything was successful? Sorry I am still new to programming. In first year right now.

Comment: @TakShing `NULL` is a pointer, but your function returns an integer. You have to return an integer. NULL is not an integer.

Comment: And yes, `const char *` is actally just a pointer to the start of the string (nothing like varchar in SQL) so `if (filename == NULL)` works. `if (filename)` also works, because pointers are `false` only when they are `NULL`. But I'd **really** recommend at this point reading "The C Programming Language", before you get very confused.

Comment: I see, since I am not allowed to change the return type of the function ( as specified by my professor), is using "return;" valid?

Comment: `return;` without a value won't work either. That would just return some unpredictable (undefined) number.

Comment: ;/ ;(. What should I return when I encounter a NULL then?

Comment: That depends on what this function is for. What is the return type supposed to do? Does it give the length of a string? The number of entries in an array? Your question doesn't say.

Comment: My function in gist only writes to a open file, so if all is good and okay I just return 0.

Comment: So, do you only need two return values, one meaning "OK" and one meaning "failure"? In that case, I would return 1 for "OK" and zero for "not OK". 1 is used for "true" in C, and 0 for "false".

Comment: Yup, you completely read my mind there, I only use the function to write the elements in my array to an open text file. I won't be using any stuff it returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the return type is `int`, you can't return a `NULL`. To show an error, you could instead return a special value like zero or -1, if you check for that value in any calling function. Lots of functions return nonnegative numbers on success, or -1 on error.

`NULL` cannot be stored in an `int` variable, unlike in SQL, for example. If you ignore the warning and return `NULL` anyway, then `NULL` will be casted to zero. The calling function won't be able to tell whether you returned `NULL` or zero.

If your function only needs to indicate success or failure, then it's common to return 1 for success, and zero for failure. Zero means "false" when treated as a boolean value (like in `if` statements), and non-zero means "true."

Comment: Strange, I do recall returning NULl in multiple functions that were expecting an int return type? O.o, I will have to check again. Would returning -1 act as a NULL? I realize that this isn't that important, but I got a segmentation fault when I passed my func a null, so I watn to proof it against such possibilities.

Comment: **NO returning `-1` NEVER acts as NULL** A `null` values is `0`, as a pointer the value is `NULL`.

Comment: If you return -1, you should have to have the calling function check for that value explicitly. And of course, this won't work if -1 is already a valid return value for that function.

Comment: What I mean is, would returning -1 when ia is null sufficient, because normally I would return NULL, but we can't seem to do that in m yprogram.

Comment: If you are never going to return a negative number except to signify an error, then returning -1 to show that something bad happened should be fine. Just make sure that any functions that call this function know what to do with a -1.

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I am just calling it and not setting a variable to store the return value of the function.

Comment: What do you guys suggest to do in, for instance, a function that's supposed to return the value contained in a node of an AVL tree, (the value can be negative or positive) therefore, I can't return -1, 0 or 1 to indicate the failure of the function as all of those are valid values that could be found in the AVL tree. So for instance, in my function, if I get passed a NULL pointer as the pointer to the AVL tree, what should be returned?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've misunderstood what `NULL` means in C. Types are not nullable. `NULL` is effectively just a shorthand for the pointer with value `0`! And `int` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int? intarr_save_binary( intarr_t* ia, const char* filename )
```