# When are you able to return NULL as the returning value of a C function?

Tags: c, pointers, return-value, null-pointer

I was wondering if you could tell me when you are able to return `NULL`, as the result of a function in C.

For instance `int lenght()` can't return `NULL` because is is expecting an `int` in the return statement.

But the function `struct node* find(int key)`, when working with linked lists allows me to return NULL.

Comment: Pointer versus not pointer. `NULL` is a null-pointer value.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096623/unable-to-return-null-in-a-function-that-expects-an-integer-return-type This Link will Help you

Answer (score 5):

`NULL` is a pointer value - or rather a null-pointer value.

`NULL` means that the function can't find where your pointer should point to - for example if you want to open a file, but it doesn't work your file pointer is returned as `NULL`. So you can test the value of a pointer and check to see if it worked or not.

If you are writing a routine

```
int length()
```

then you could return a negative value if length is unable to read the length of whatever you send it - this would be a way of indicating an error, because normally lengths can never be negative....

Answer (score 3):

It is a **matter of *convention*** and you should clearly have one in your head and *document* it (at least in comments).

Sometimes a pointer really should always point to a valid address (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8403447/841108) `intSwap` example, both arguments should be valid pointers). At other times, it should either be such a valid address, or be `NULL`. Conceptually the pointer type is then *by convention* a [*sum type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (between genuine pointer addresses and the special `NULL` value).

Notice that the C language does not have a type (or a notation) which enforces that some given pointer is always valid and non-null. BTW, with GCC specifically, you can [annotate a function](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) with `__attribute__` using `nonnull` to express that a given argument is never null.

A typical example is `FILE*` pointers in [`<stdio.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io). The `fopen` function is documented to be able to return `NULL` (on failure), or some valid pointer. But the `fprintf` function is expecting a *valid* pointer (and passing `NULL`  to it as the first argument is some [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), often a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault); and UB is really [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108)).

Some non-portable programs even use several "special" pointer values (which should not be dereferenced), e.g. (on Linux/x86-64) `#define SPECIAL_SLOT (void*)((intptr_t)-1)` (which we know that on Linux it is never a valid address). Then we could have the convention that a pointer is a valid pointer to a valid memory zone, or `NULL` or `SPECIAL_SLOT` (hence, if seen as an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type), it is a sum type of two distinct invalid pointers `NULL` and `SPECIAL_SLOT` and the set of valid addresses). Another example is `MAP_FAILURE` as result of [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) on Linux.

BTW, when using pointers in C to heap allocated data (indirectly obtained with `malloc`), you also need conventions about who is in charge of releasing the data (by using `free`, often thru a supplied function to free a data and all its internal stuff).

**Good C programming requires many *explicit conventions* regarding pointers**, and it is essential to understand them precisely and document them well. Look for example[s] into [GTK](http://gtk.org/). Read also about [`restrict`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict).

Answer (score 1):

> When are you able to return NULL as the returning value of a C function

In general, if and only if the function returns a pointer type:

```
T * function(<parameter definitions> | void>); /* With T being any valid type. */
```

---

There are other,  corner cases, which depend on the C implementation in use.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is definitely a pointer. So if your function is expected to return a pointer and for some reason cannot, it should return the obvious "invalid pointer", which is NULL.

Comment: @alk The standard: *An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type  void *, is called a null pointer constant*. Don't tell me a "null pointer constant" is not a pointer, please.

Comment: Well yes, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

NULL may be defined as **0** or **(void*)0** (See [6.3.2.3p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) and [7.19p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3)).

Consequently,  it may be always used as a return value in functions returning a *pointer type*, and depending on implementation, it may be potentially usable as a return value in functions returning *numerical types*, though the latter is a bad idea, as `NULL` is expected to be used in association with pointers.